# is the asteriod belt linear or 360 degrees

Tags: asteroid

What I'am trying to understand if in space does the asteriod belt "sit" on a linear orbit or does it encompass a 360 degree orbit? (in a plane Cartesian coordinate system)

Comment: Short answer: Main belt is ring-shaped, but lots of asteroids orbit at weird inclinations as well. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_belt

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of the solar system is in the same plane thus the belt is also mostly flat and circular in shape.

This video explain the reasons:
http://www.universetoday.com/108355/why-is-the-solar-system-flat/

Comment: Toroidal in shape is a better way of describing it.